# Differential map on the vector space of polynomials: Kernel and Image

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, proof-writing

Given the $V_n$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq$ n over $\Bbb R$

So $M_D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & ... & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 2 &... 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 &.\\ . & . & . &. \\ . & . & . &.  \\ . & . & . &n \\ 0  & 0 &0 &...0 \end{bmatrix}$

Where D is the differential map.How would I prove Image of D ~= $V_{n-1}$  and that the kernel of  D ~= $\Bbb R $

Does the result hold if $V_n$ was of $\Bbb Z_2$

Forgive my appalling mathjax

These claims about the kernel and image do indeed make sense. However, I really do not have a idea on how to proof rigorously

Answer (score 4):

The standard monomials $1,x,x^2,...,x^{n}$ form a basis.  What does $D$ to to this basis?  Do you know how to write the matrix of a linear operator with respect to a basis?

Comment: @Steven_Gubkin D(1) =0 , D(x) =1 ,..., D($x^n$) = $nx^n-1$ , but How do represent each D(i) is a linear combination of the basis

Comment: You *have* written each $D(x^i)$ as a linear combination of the basis.  $D(x^i) = ix^{i-1}$, and $x^{i-1}$ is another basis element!

Comment: @Steven_Gubkin Any thoughts

Comment: ?  You flagged my answer?  This is not a site for you to scramble to have other people do your homework at the last minute.  It is a place for doing mathematics.

Comment: You're right that I should have not flagged you. For this I apologise. However, I do not appreciated the lecture. I wasn't not doing my homework at the last minute, though I do understand why you would think that.  I have a disability, namely my hand function is limited and because of this I write and type at a very slow pace. Some lecturers are unwilling to accommodate me in this regards, and I often have to scramble to meet due date despite starting as early as I can.

Comment: Furthermore, I do not expect anyone to do my homework for me. This would not benefit me in the long run. I do get stuck on a question from time to time, and sometimes require help. However any problem I attempt I want to understand, not just complete.

Comment: I hope we could put this mistake behind us.

Comment: @Steven_Gubkin I apologize again

Comment: Apology accepted. Good work writing down the matrix for the linear map.